# Always `Could not bind to tcp://my_ip_here:8080 Address already in use`

Tags: php, sockets, zeromq, ratchet

I was trying to deploy my websocket server and start running it but always gives:

```
PHP Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'React\Socket\ConnectionException'
with message       'Could not bind to tcp://my_ip_here:8080:
                    Address already in use'
in                 /var/www/html/webscoket/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php:29
```

here's my `server.php`:

```
<?php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use React\Socket\Server;
use React\ZMQ\Context;

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$app    = new onyxsocket();
$webSock = new Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8080, 'my_ip_here');
$webServer = new IoServer(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            $app
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$context = new Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://my_ip_here:5555');
$pull->on('error', function ($e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
});
$pull->on('message', array($app, 'onbroadcast'));
$loop->run();
```

What I've tried so far is to check available ports that can be used in the production server: `netstat - anp` gave me idea that port `8080` is free. But the problem is it still show the error Address already in use. I also tried other ports given by the administrator but no luck.

The `server.php` that I'm trying to deploy is working fine on localhost. But I don't know what do I need to do to make it work on a production server.

Need help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you see when you visit http://your-ip-here:8080?

Comment: i cannot see it: webpage not available

Comment: i tried `telnet my_ip_here 8080`, then it displays a blank screen which means it's free. also tried the `fsockopen` from php and also and it's also okay. idk where's the problem. since i just follow the tutorial from socketo.me.

Comment: I don't think blank screen means it's free.it's quite the opposite.you should get a connection error.try a different port.

Comment: i already tried other ports that is on LISTEN state. still no luck.

Comment: the server is nginx by the way. thanks.

Comment: Clarify the code, pls. Your server-code ZeroMQ `.bind()` -s to **port# 5555. So whose code binds to localhost port# 8080, that is reported in an unhandled exception above?** How do you clean for a gracefull-exit any crashed `EventLoop/Factory` to release resources and avoid hanging orphans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from @user3666197 comment above:

> Clarify the code, pls. Your server-code ZeroMQ .bind() -s to port# 5555. So whose code binds to localhost port# 8080, that is reported in an unhandled exception above? How do you clean for a gracefull-exit any crashed EventLoop/Factory to release resources and avoid hanging orphans?

I decided to recheck the netstat: `netstat -tulpen` and check for the ports 8080 and 5555 and find out that there is registered PID on the port currently connecting. These application was also the same script that I want to run on console, `server.php`.

I kill the PID: `kill PID_number` and run the `server.php` on console again. It worked.

Comment: i also experience the same problem, and did the solution mentioned above. but there are no PID numbers when i do netstat -tulpen.

Comment: I have same  issue, there is no PID.

Comment: Use `sudo netstat ...` to see the PID.